# Unity How to declare propertly Input Actions in Script CS0246

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following a tutorial for scripting Input Actions in Unity

After finished coding what the tutorial told I've got this error in the declarations of Input System's stuff `CS0246 The type or namespace name 'InputActions' could not be found`

The code that causes the error is:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class GameInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    private InputActions InputActions;
    private InputAction StartAction;
    void Start() {
        InputActions = new InputActions();
        }
    private void OnEnable() {
        StartAction = InputActions.Start.Start;
        StartAction.Enable();

        InputActions.Start.Start.performed += StartGame;
        InputActions.Start.Start.Enable();
    }
    public void StartGame(InputValue value) {
        // CODE HERE
    }
}
```

The error is caused by the declaration `private InputActions InputActions;`
I think it is by the variable type `InputActions` that may not exist.
But the tutorial also uses a type that doesen't exist.

How can I make Unity to recognize the InputActions type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo: Unity does not have an `InputActions` Type, but it has a `InputAction` Type. See how you spelled the type different in your example. `InputActions` does not exist so you can't use it.

Change `InputActions` to `InputAction`.

Comment: @GospelBG Also: Don't name a variable exactly like the type it is representing. It works, but it is confusing and is considered bad style.